# Redirect unloggedin users

Tags: plugins, php, redirect, urls

I added the following code via the cPanel to the function.php file.

```
    add_action('template_redirect','woo_check_loggedin');

function woo_check_loggedin(){
   // this condition checks for certian pages

      // if user is not logged in we redirect him to login page you can also show error message instead of redirect if that the requirment.
      if(!is_user_logged_in() && !is_page(lost-password) ){
          wp_redirect("https://example.com/wp-login.php");
          exit;
      }
      

   }
```

But, when I now go e.g. to mysite.com/shop it still works (I can visit every site). How can I avoid that? Because the site should only be avaiable for loggedin users. (But only the admin can create Logins).

Comment: is there a reason `lost-password` has no quotes? are you sure this isn't page caching or CDN caching?

Comment: The link: https://example.com/myaccount/lost-password needs to be reachable.

Comment: I understand, but your code has `is_page(lost-password)` and not `is_page("lost-password")`, have you tried adding the quotes? `""`. Are you sure that the function runs?

Comment: You probably want [auth_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/auth_redirect/) rather than wp_redirect with a hard-coded URL.

Comment: Which functions.php did you put this in? If it's a plugin are you sure that plugin is active? You could try adding a deliberate typo to the file and check that breaks the site temporarily.

Comment: I put it in the normal functions.php I didn't use a plugin. And how can I add the auth redirect()

Comment: When I enter the link in the URL Bar, I can still see the site